# Qt use QImage load many file

Tags: qt, memory, qimage

i'm newbie in Qt

I'm trying to use QImage load many image

but I found a problem,

when my program use more than 1.4GB memory, then I could not continue loading image,

It will output " QImage: out of memory,return a null image "

but, I'm pretty sure I have enough memory not use

does anyone know where is the problem?

thank you very much

Comment: 32 bit or 64? 32 bit in windows only gets 2 gig to work with

Comment: Are you loading many images using the same QImage object, or you load many images and all of them remain in the memory? Why does your memory increase?

Comment: I want to clarify... You are using 64 bit Qt + 64 bit compiler? I'm not asking about your OS. I'm asking about Qt. Do you build it by yourself?

Comment: when I load one Image, I will pushback in the vector ( QVector<QImage> ) @@

Comment: http://imgur.com/e2MTPpm
I found I am use Qt 32bit, this is why I have this problem?
If I download Qt 64 bit and compiler my code, 32 Bit OS can run my program?
thank you very much